# Finite summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am struggling with following sum, can any body comment how I can attack this one? any bounds or approximations would help

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{n} i^2 a^{i^2} = a+ 4a^4 +9 a^9 +16 a^{16} +...+n^2 a^{n^2}
\end{equation}

Comment: What should you do with it?

Comment: @user251257 in idealistic way, I am trying to have closed form for that, like the one that we have for geometric series. But it seems elusive , so I am OK with a simple expression as a function of n & a .

Comment: Let $\displaystyle \phi(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{N} x^{k^2}$ then $\displaystyle x \frac{d\phi(x)}{dx} = \sum_{k=0}^{N} k^2x^{k^2}$

Comment: @SommeGuy hwta makes you think , this is an upper bound?